# Polymer takes too long to load

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, polymer

I build up a small web application using the [Polymer Project](http://polymer-project.org) but it takes up to 12 seconds to load. My HTML and JavaScript files are loaded immediately but then I get a blank page until all polymer elements are loaded and rendered.
It seems that all polymer files are loaded in sequence instead of parrallel and therefore take so long time.

[image]

My index.html looks like this:

```
....
<!-- Polymer HTML includes -->
<link rel="import" href="bower_components/core-toolbar/core-toolbar.html">
<link rel="import" href="bower_components/core-menu/core-menu.html">
<link rel="import" href="bower_components/core-item/core-item.html">
<link rel="import" href="bower_components/core-header-panel/core-header-panel.html">
<link rel="import" href="bower_components/core-drawer-panel/core-drawer-panel.html">
<link rel="import" href="bower_components/core-icons/core-icons.html">
<link rel="import" href="bower_components/core-collapse/core-collapse.html">
<link rel="import" href="bower_components/core-selector/core-selector.html">
<link rel="import" href="bower_components/paper-elements/paper-elements.html">
<link rel="import" href="bower_components/font-roboto/roboto.html">

<!-- My customly created elements -->
<link rel="import" href="elements/overview-item.html">
<link rel="import" href="elements/contacts-item.html">
<link rel="import" href="elements/chat-bubble-right.html">
....
```

How can I get this faster?

EDIT: I am using the latest version of Polymer (think it's 0.5.1).

Comment: [Vulcanize](https://github.com/Polymer/vulcanize) it. It will concatenate your gazillion components / html files into a single file. Should drastically reduce number of requests and save you quite some time.

Comment: Thank you, this tool looks promising. But I get an error when trying to open by vulcanized .html file.
[--> Screenshot](http://data1.root-space.eu/i1/i1rro9nh.png)
I don't know, what it tries to tell me. The elements mentioned there are my custom created polymer elements.